# Formatação django template numero decimal

Tags: django, formatação, django-templates, django-2.0

Estou tendo problemas na exibição dos resultados de um calculo.
Eu tenho um campo DecimalField e quero retornar ele formatado dessa maneira:

```
1.000.000,00
```

Se eu mando exibir normalmente sem tags, fica assim:

```
1000000,00
```

Se eu adiciono `{{value|floatformat:2}}` fica igual:

```
1000000,00
```

Se eu faço o load do humanize e adiciono um intcomma (`{{value|floatformat:2|intcomma}}` fica assim:

```
1,000,000,00
```

Eu não estou sabendo resolver esse problema.
Meu `settings.py` está dessa forma:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-BR'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adicione em settings (considerando as suas outras configurações, não há necessidade do humanize):

```
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR='.',
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR=True
```

Na template:

```
{% load l10n %}

...

{{valor | floatformat:2}}
```

Exemplo de uma saída em que pego o valor digitado e multiplico por 2:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Resolveu, obrigado! Só não foi necessário o load do l10n pois o floatformat é padrão do django template se não me engano.